# Reducing space between shiny dashboard elements contained in a box

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

In the app below, I wrap two plots in a `box` function to add borders around them to visually distinguish one from the other. However, when doing this, I get an unnecessary amount of whitespace between my input selector and the plots. Can anyone tell me how I can reduce this space. I'm guessing that the solution is using `css` but I couldn't figure out how to implement it correctly:

**Edit:** Any potential solutions, just wanted to clarify that the two smaller boxes must exist within the bigger 'Statistics' box.

[image]

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinydashboardPlus)
library(tidyverse)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(title = "Statistics", width = 12, collapsible = T,
          sliderInput("numSelect", "Select Value", min = 1, max = 10, value = 5, width = "25%"),
          fluidRow(
            column(width = 6, box(width = NULL, plotOutput("cars1"))),
            column(width = 6, box(width = NULL, plotOutput("cars2"))))
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$cars1 <- renderPlot(
    mtcars %>% 
      sample_n(input$numSelect) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
      geom_point()
  )
  output$cars2 <- renderPlot(
    mtcars %>% 
      sample_n(input$numSelect) %>% 
      ggplot(aes(x = mpg, y = hp)) +
      geom_point()
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to add CSS to your app, but if you only want to affect one single element you can pass the CSS in the argument `style` that is possible for most of the Shiny functions. In your case you can add the style `margin-top` to the `fluidRow` to move the two plots 20 pixels up. The function will looks like this:

`fluidRow(style = "margin-top: -20px;",`

You can change the value that best fits your needs.